# Thymeleaf Exception parsing document in Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Error message reads:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Exception parsing document: template="register", line 15
>   - column 3

If I remove the form, where I use `th:`, then it displays the page correctly. But with the form I get the error. I can't see any error in my code and would appreciate someone taking a look.

register.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>User Registration</h3>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <p>First Name:</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}">
    <p>Last Name:</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}">
    <p>Password:</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{password}">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

UserController.java:

```
package com.demo.spring.controller;

import com.demo.spring.domain.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registerView(Model model)
    {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "register";
    }

}
```

User.java:

```
package com.demo.spring.domain;

public class User {

    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String password;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer, you'll likely want `input type="password"` on the password field.  And use the shorthand `@GetMapping` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have missed the closing tag of `<input>` element.

for ex: use this

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}"/>
```

instead of

```
 <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}">
```

`Thymeleaf` can only handle valid `XML`.it only works with well-formed XML, so if you want to use `HTML5` template mode your HTML must be well-formed XML. Otherwise, you can use `LEGACYHTML5` template